# Show Value Only If Not Empty - PHP

Tags: php

I've got a form where some fields are optional.  I later display these fields.

I'm trying to show a value from my database only if there is a value.  Otherwise, show nothing.

Here is what needs to be displayed if there is a value -

```
<div class='category' style='font-size:20px; background-color:f2f2f2'>".$row['project_category']."</div>
```

Should I use an 'if (strlen($prjcat) > 0)'?

Thanks!

Comment: `if(!empty(FIELD)) { SHOW FIELD; }`.. ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/empty

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an `if` statement to check if the value is empty:

```
if(!empty($row['project_category'])){
    echo "<div class='category' style='font-size:20px; background-color:f2f2f2'>".$row['project_category']."</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has just the function you're looking for ~ [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/function.empty.php)...

```
<?php if (!empty($row['project_category'])) : ?>
<div class="category" style="font-size:20px; background-color:f2f2f2;">
    <?= htmlspecialchars($row['project_category']) ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

or, if you're looping over some field names

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $field) : ?>
    <?php if (!empty($row[$field])) : ?>
    <div class="category" style="font-size:20px; background-color:f2f2f2;">
        <?= htmlspecialchars($row[$field]) ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use this

```
<?php if(trim($row['project_category']) != "") { ?>
     <div class="category" style="font-size:20px; background-color:f2f2f2"> <?php echo $row['project_category']; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Do not use empty if your column value can have zero. Because when you use `empty($row['project_category'])` and `$row['project_category'] = 0` it will return true.
For more info check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score -1):

You can try out not empty for this:

```
if(!empty($row['project_category'])){
    echo '<div class="category" style="font-size:20px; background-color:f2f2f2">'.$row['project_category'].'</div>';
}
```

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea to use `'` for quoting the whole string. And the missing `echo` was a typo?

Comment: Correct Tom. However it is slightly faster to use single quotes. PHP won't use additional processing to interpret what is inside the single quote.when you use double quotes PHP has to parse to check if there is any variables in there.